# Why does php form works fine with value="name" not value="$_POST['value']"?

Tags: php

Need some help here. The code run fine with fixed value insert but problem having variables. All I get is empty name. Double checked but can't find the problem. Any help is appreciated.

mysql output:

```
id name
5
```

code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  header('Location: index.php');
}

include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = '';
$name = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name_error = 'Name is required';
  } else {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
    // check if name contains only letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
      $name_error = 'Only letters and white space allowed';
    }
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('" . $name . "')";

  if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($connection));
  }

}

?>


<!-- create account  -->
<form class="form-inline" action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

  <!-- name -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="register_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" size="35" required>
  </div>

  <!-- submit -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat"></input>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: *All I get is empty for name, email, password, and department* Where you get this? in database you never insert *email*, *Password* and so on

Comment: Field name in form is `register_name` not `name`

Comment: you have only id and name in your db, and name is empty. then how do you show this empty name in textbox? confirm your question again before post here

Comment: my bad I cut my script short to name only

Comment: @Jens thanks for tips about prepared statement to prevent SQL injection. Very useful thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `$_POST['name']` to `$_POST['register_name']`

because you use `register_name` in `form field`